# How to change the template from Widget to Main Window?

Tags: qt

When I started my application, I chose a wrong template in Qt Designer.

I did File -> New -> Widget.

Now I need a menu. So, I need the Main Window template, I suppose.

Can I change the template seamless or I have to create new form and drug everything onto it?

Comment: With the designer, you may need to create a new form and copy and paste over your widgets to the new form. With modifying your window's class files, you can try sub-classing a different widget such as QDialog or QWidget, but it won't change how the designer handles the widget. Also, is this Qt 4.x or Qt 5.x?

Comment: I have to say that there being no built-in way to do this is a *major* annoyance. I get it that this is not a everyday thing, but the idea that people will make this decisions exactly once and always get it right is ... baffling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me three line edits in two files to change a `QWidget` template to a `QMainWindow`.

Just now in Qt 4.8.4, I did the following:

I opened the ui file outside of Qt Creator (after it was closed in Qt Creator) and I edited a line in the file:

EDIT:  Make a backup of what you are working on, because this editing the ui file is a little un-kosher, and could have strange, undefined repercussions.

widget.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Widget</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="Widget"> <!-- This is the line I edited...
 "QMainWindow" was "QWidget".-->
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Widget</string>
  </property>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QMainWindow>// Edited this line, too

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QMainWindow // Edited this line.
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

End result: now Qt Creator/Designer allows me to add a toolbar, a menubar, a statusbar, etc, just by right clicking in the blank area of the now QMainWindow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Changing `QWidget` to `QMainWindow` in the XML caused child elements to disappear.

Comment: This is not sufficient in Qt 5. You also need the changes that [Aleksey discusses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36301593/2509). Apparently because something is making assumptions about the structure of widget tree under a `QMainWindow`.

Answer (score 4):

Need to create new ui form with Main Window template and copy widget content to it, because main window has central widget, and if we do not specify it, this causes child elements to disappear as mentioned above.

If You edit XML in .ui then changing `QWidget` to `QMainWindow` is not enough. First need to add:

```
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
```

element before all widgets or layouts, right after

```
<property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
</property>
```

element (order may differ). And add correspondent tag `</widget>` for closing central widget element after all - before closing element for main widget `</widget>` (before `<customwidgets>` or `<resources>`). This works for me.

Comment: I want to add that this step is also required when changing to a `QDockWidget`.